# .isalpha() returns false on a specific example

Tags: python

In a given string you should reverse every word, but the words should stay in their places.

**Input**: A string.

**Output**: A string.

**Precondition**: The line consists only from alphabetical symbols and spaces.

```
def backward_string_by_word(text: str) -> str:
    # your code here
    word = str()
    for i in text:
        if i.isalpha():
            word += i
        else:
            text = text.replace(word,word[::-1])
            word = ''
        if i.isalpha() and text.index(i) == text.index(text[-1]):
            text = text.replace(word,word[::-1])
    return text
```

I'm still in elementary level so excuse my simple answers, I know there are much easier ways to solve this but I want to learn where the code I made is failing.

*My approach*
The loop begins a string is created which adds characters until `.isalpha()` returns false. Then I replace the string within the original text and reset the string for the next word until the loop ends.
This worked fine with the first 4 examples given to me; ***''***, ***'world'***, ***'hello world'***, ***'hello   world'***.
for some reason, in the fifth example *'welcome to a game'*, the code returned ***'ewlcome ot a emag'*** instead of ***'emoclew ot a emag'***. Please help me understand what happened with the first word in the text.

Comment: what happened at the first word in the string is still a mystery to me, because only the first two letters were swapped but the remaining letters remained in their place. I just couldn't deduct how that happened.

Comment: str.split is certainly better, but the OP wants help solving the bug with the existing code. Maybe we should help with that first so he can learn, instead of just providing a new solution.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes you are correct, but could you please help me understand how the code ran please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because of your second check:

```
if i.isalpha() and text.index(i) == text.index(text[-1]):
```

Note that `text[-1]` is the last letter which is also `e`. But [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) returns the ***first*** index found so when `i` equals the first `'e'`, you have:

```
text.index(text[-1]) == text.index(i) == text.index('e') == 1
```

It would make more sense to do:

```
if i.isalpha() and text.index(i) == len(text)-1:
```

Which will also fail from the same reason (when actually reaching the last `e`, it will return `1`). This check is simply not necessary. Just add the last `replace` outside the loop:

```py
def backward_string_by_word(text: str) -> str:
    word = ''
    for char in text:
        if char.isalpha():
            word += char
        else:
            text = text.replace(word, word[::-1])
            word = ''

    return text.replace(word, word[::-1])
```

---

A simpler solution will be to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string according to the words and reverse each one separately. `split` returns a list so we can [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) it and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) it back in the end:

```py
def backward_string_by_word(text: str) -> str:
    words = text.split()
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        words[i] = word[::-1]
    return ' '.join(words)
```

It can be even further reduced by creating a new list of reversed words:

```py
def backward_string_by_word(text: str) -> str:
    return ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in text.split())
```

Comment: Beat me to it, but yep this is the issue. If it run into any letter that is the same as the last letter in the entire string, then it will make a swap, which is not the desired behavior.

Comment: I see, understood. how should I make the replacement at the end of the loop in the case where more than one word is introduced in the string

Comment: @Ammar As I said, just add the last `replace` outside the loop without any condition. You always want to add the last word...

Comment: I think it would be resolved if we can somehow get the index of the letter without mentioning it to avoid that issue. Should I create an external counter or do you have something better in mind